# MySQL Connector and MySQL Server Version 4.0.25

Tags: version, mysql-connector

I'm trying to use the MySQL Connector/Net to connect a c# program to a MySQL Server.

Problem is, the MySQL server is version 4.x, and the connector throws this exception:

*Connector/Net no longer supports server versions prior to 5.0*

Is there a way to connect to this older MySQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam, I have a copy of MyODBC-standard-3.51.9-win.msi if that is of any use, I can email it to you.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [MySQL Connector/NET 6.3.0 change history](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/connector-net-news-6-3-0.html):

> Support for MySQL Server 4.1 has been
>   removed from MySQL Connector/NET
>   starting with version 6.3.0. The
>   connector will now throw an exception
>   if you try to connect to a server of
>   version less than 5.0.

However by installing an earlier version of the Connector you will still be able to connect to MySQL Server version 4.1. For example, I was able to successfully connect to MySQL Server version 4.1.25 using MySQL Connector/NET 6.2.4.